# send a varible through load functon

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i would like to send a variable on the next page this is what i have at the moment

```
<? php 
//some code 
$ID = $_GET['ID']; 
echo "<div id='show_here'></div>";

    <script type ="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(function(){
          $('#show_here').load('fetch.php') 
      }, 3000);
    });
    </script>
```

so i would like to send the variable `$ID` in to the next page i assume it will be something like this `.load(fetch.php?=id=$id')` but it doesn't work can some one please help me out here 
i think the first think is to define the variable `id` in the `jQuery` part but i do not know how to go about it please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd clean that code up properly before anything else.

```
<? php 
//some code 
$ID = $_GET['ID'];
?>


<div id='show_here'></div>

<script type ="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
      $('#show_here').load('fetch.php?id=<?php echo $ID; ?>') // we put the ID here 
  }, 3000);
});
</script>
```

In your `fetch.php` file, you'll need to access the `$ID` via `$_GET` again.

I'm sticking within the scope of your question here, but something to note is that you best sanitize that information. **Especially** if you're going to use it in a database query!

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
.load('fetch.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>');
```

or

```
.load('fetch.php' , {id : '<?php echo $id ?>'}) ;
```